# PHP Symbolic Link in Pathname

Tags: php, directory, lamp, symlink

I'm working on a simple means of listing all files in a directory via php.  I have [code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) directly from php.net which does this, but I seem to have trouble accessing symbolic links.  When I try to access a symbolic link (to a directory), getcwd() will display the original working directory.

index1.php is the file for this.  I am running on arch linux.

`ls -lh` of directory.  permissions appear to be in order?

```
[drake@unimatrix434 .hiddenVideo]$ pwd
/home/drake/public_html/.hiddenVideo
[drake@unimatrix434 .hiddenVideo]$ ls -lh
total 224K
-rw-r--r-- 1 drake users  921 Nov 13 20:17 index1.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 drake users 213K Nov 13 15:19 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 drake users 4.0K Nov 13 20:05 testDIR
lrwxrwxrwx 1 drake users   26 Nov 13 14:10 Video -> /media/storage_pool/Video/
```

php code section:

```
<?php
    echo "<div>" . getcwd() . "</div>";
    chdir('Video');
    echo "<div>" . getcwd() . "</div>";

    echo "</br>";

    //list files
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        echo "<div>Directory handle: $handle</div>";
        echo "<div>Entries:</div>";

        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            echo "<div>$entry</div>";
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Which yields:

```
/home/drake/public_html/.hiddenVideo
/home/drake/public_html/.hiddenVideo

Directory handle: Resource id #3
Entries:
..
index.php
.
Video
index1.php
testDIR
```

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?  I would have thought this would work...

Answer (score 0):

Try with [readlink()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php)
You should be able to transform the link into the dir...
and use [is_link()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php) to verify if it actually is one =)

Comment: Make sure you are using FULL PATH